# Unable to addLiquidity from pancakeSwap fork

Tags: solidity, blockchain, pancakeswap

[image]

I have forked pancakeSwap core and periphery and successfully migrated them on bscTestnet.
I have also retrieved the init has code from factory and replaced it on router library.

When i tried to call addLiquidity i am getting the below error.

```
const token1Contract = new web3.eth.Contract(Token1.abi, tokenOneAddress);
    const token2Contract = new web3.eth.Contract(Token2.abi, tokenTwoAddress);
    await token1Contract.methods.approve(routerAddress, 10000).send({
      from: account,
    });
    await token2Contract.methods.approve(routerAddress, 10000).send({
      from: account,
    });
    const Router02Contract = new web3.eth.Contract(Router02.abi, routerAddress);
    await Router02Contract.methods
      .addLiquidity(
        tokenOneAddress,
        tokenTwoAddress,
        10000,
        10000,
        10000,
        10000,
        account,
        Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 10
      )
      .send({
        from: account,
        gasLimit: "100000",
      })
      .on("error", (error) => {
        console.log("my error", error.message);
      });
```

Comment: Are you following eat the blocks' tutorial to add liquidity?

Comment: The issue was with hex in the pancakeLibrary.

Comment: could you please post the answer too?
or better post all you test suit.

Comment: according to a hidden answer "The issue was with hex in the pancakeLibrary."